# Update a column in one table when it is linked with another table in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to update address column in User class using HQL. address_id is linked to Address using structure shown below. I want help on how to do so using HQL .

```
 class User{
    int id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="address_id")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private Address  address ;
}

class Address{
    @Id
    @Column(name="address_id")
    int address_id;
    String city;
    String state;   
}
```

This is what my HQl query looks like but I am not sure how to pass whole object as query parameter

```
String hql = "update from User set id= null where address=:address ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use annotation `@Query` and `@Modifying`

Retrieve Address object by,

```java
Address address = select address from address where address.id=XYZ
```

and latter use `address` object however you want. 
ie.

```java
@Modifying
@Query("update from User set id= null where address=?1";
void updateAddress(address);
// fyi here ?1 rectifies argument id
```

Comment: I tried using the query in hql and I was not able to achieve the desired result. Do you know if we can perform the update using hql?

Comment: If you can add more details in question re. what is expected it will be helpful